# Optimizing IN clauses with thousands of integers

Tags: mysql, performance, index, mysql-8.0

I have a search engine that outputs the id's of the elements to show in the search results, or to use in an "analytics" module.

In this one, I perform a lot of different queries to show insights in a dashboard.

The SQL's used to be:

```
select {fields with calculations, max, count, whatever ...}
joining {with tables needed to join}
where {some wheres necessary for the query}
and element.id in (xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx ...)
```

The problem is when that "in clause" contains more than 1000 elements.

SQL query start to be slow (more than 1 second).

Those ID's are integers, they refer to the PRIMARY KEY (integer) of the main element table.

But, as I said, when I have to handle 2000 or 3000 id's in that clause, the query is very slow.

Any ideas of performance?

I thought about a temporary table (for that dashboard page load) with all those ID's and perform all queries with a JOIN to that temporary table full of those id's ... but times are exactly the same.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO my_temp_table VALUES (34), (45), (17321), (27320),... 6000 more ...
```

and then performing a Join to this table for the other queries...

Results seems better, but if I have 10 persons visiting the dashboard page, Mysql will have to handle 10 temporary tables ... is this OK for Mysql Server ?

Is the better solution ?

Note: I'm in MySQL 8.0 ... I don't have "table-valued parameter" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066869/311188)

Comment: Please provide some more info on the query, perhaps giving a realistic sample.  There may be _other_ ways to optimize the query.,

Answer (score 0):

"*but if I have 10 persons visiting the dashboard page, Mysql will have to handle 10 temporary tables ... is this OK for Mysql Server ?*" - I don't see why not, 10 temporary tables is  not a lot, and using temporary tables to `JOIN` to is usually an efficient relational means to filter other tables. The `IN` clause *can* cause performant issues (especially with multiple values) because it's the equivalent of a bunch of `OR` statements.

Comment: I wanted to have more hope in the IN clause with 10000 elements because they were all numerical, but no ...

Comment: @FlamingMoe It doesn't matter what the data type is, unfortunately that's just a general shortcoming of the `IN` clause.

Comment: Furthermore, the 10 temp tables would be in 10 different connections.  The main contention is due to 10 _connections_ busy at the same time, not the number of temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL 8 you can try using `JSON_TABLE` to `JOIN` on a JSON array.

For example:

```
INNER JOIN JSON_TABLE(?, '$[*]' COLUMNS (id INT PATH '$')) AS t ON t.id = element.id
```

Then you only need to pass the IDs as JSON array (with only integers simply formatting them as comma separated list and putting [] around them can be done without needing a JSON encoder).

This avoids having to manually create a temporary table.

It also works for empty lists unlike naive `IN (?)` expansion, which often needs extra logic in the application.

In my experience joining on a JSON array using `JSON_TABLE` can often be faster than `IN (...)` with as few as 4 elements.

Comment: Sure, _simpler_ than a temp table, but I can't imagine that it would be any _faster_.

Comment: I have implemented the temporary table ... do you think JSON_TABLE will be as fast as temporary table ... in my case I handle about 6000 id's